# Testing the saving method in Spring using Postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

I am building rest api using spring framework, just for learning and I have some problem when saving data with relationship .
I am building kind of bookstore and my book entity looks like this

```
@Entity
public class Book {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String title;

  private String isbn;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Author author;

  public long getId() {
     return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
     this.id = id;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
     return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
     this.title = title;
  }

  public String getIsbn() {
     return isbn;
  }

  public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
     this.isbn = isbn;
  }

  public Author getAuthor() {
     return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(Author author) {
     this.author = author;
  }
}
```

and my author entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
  public Author(){

  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Book> books;

  public long getId() {
     return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
     this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public Set<Book> getBooks() {
     return books;
  }

  public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
     this.books = books;
  }
}
```

Now I want to check if my saving method works ok

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
public @ResponseBody
String[] create(@RequestBody Author author) {
    bookstoreRepository.save(author);
    return success;
}
```

So I want to check this using for example PostMan but unfortunately I dont know how to past good data in the program.

For title it is simple because i only send title parameter. How should it look for books ?

Comment: I guess that you pass a json. You could send as a list books:[{id:"id value", name:"name of the book", isbn:"ISBN code"}, {next book}]

Answer (score 1):

Since the POST request body is mapped to `Author`, we need to send the request that matches the Author. Something like the below one. The member `books` is a collection of type `Book` so it should be sent as JSON array.

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "name": "TAuthor Name",
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "book Title",
      "isbn": "ISBN123"
    },
    {
      "title": "book Title2",
      "isbn": "ISBN456"
    }
  ]
}
```